# blank page with wp_get_attachment

Tags: functions, images, post-meta

I want to use the function "wp_get_attachment" but when I use it, my website shows me a blank page while my server locally, the function shows me what I want...

I went through the canvas without finding an answer.

I proceed like this:

```
<div class="credit-photo">
    <h5>
        <?php
            $idPost = get_the_ID();
            $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $idPost );
            $at= wp_get_attachment( $post_thumbnail_id );

            echo $at['description'];
        ?>
    </h5>
</div>
```

the line that I think problem is :

```
$at= wp_get_attachment( $post_thumbnail_id );
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thx !

Comment: Did you check the PHP error log to find out what the error message was? a white screen of death just means that something went wrong and it put the error message in the PHP log so it wouldn't leak sensitive stuff to random visitors. Additionally, where did you get `wp_get_attachment` from? I can find no evidence such an API exists, googling provides lots of alternatives that do exist but nothing for `wp_get_attachment`

Comment: The official docs show no results for that function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment

Comment: I do not have access to the log file because my website is hosted at Wordpress. It is therefore impossible for me to use a FileZila type software).
I need to retrieve image information from the current article to display photo credits. Looking a little, I found this function in this case on this forum :)
if there is another function to retrieve information from an image, I take it with pleasure.

Comment: WordPress is a piece of open source software, it isn't a hosting service. Are you sure you don't mean you have a wordpress.com hosted site? If that's the case, you shouldn't be able to modify PHP code. Contact WordPress.com support for issues with sites hosted on WordPress.com

Comment: Also, can you link to the place you found the function in your question? There is no `wp_get_attachment` function in WordPress